# How to add arguments for run command in Mule Anypoint Studio

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I'm trying to use Mule Credentials Vault security feature from Anypoint Studio. As in Mule's example I need to have:

- *.properties* file with encrypted data
- Global element -  Similar to Mule's example

[image]

- In *mule-app.properties* - similar to Mule's example:

[image]

- When running it from command line I put the password as argument:

[image]

The error I get is:

```
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'key' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Property code could not be found
```

When I enter the password directly to the global element the app is deployed and running. 
How can I insert the password on runtime (similar to how I enter it via command line)?

Thanks, 
Keren

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to set the **code** property through *JVM argument*, insert the `-M-Dcode=24681357` in the **VM arguments** (and in the program arguments).

If you want to set the **code** property in the *mule-app.properties*, the line should be `code=24681357` instead of `-M-Dcode=24681357`.

Thoose are two ways of setting properties in mule (can use [wrapper.conf](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/32X/Passing+Additional+Arguments+to+the+JVM+to+Control+Mule) too). You should choose the one that fits your needs (and not use both simultaneously)

Comment: Thanks! Your second suggestion for _mule-app.properties_ worked. But I need the first option, using **JVM**. You are correct, I did confused with the value in _mule-app.properties_. What should it be?

Comment: @KerenSi I think that feature only works in the standalone server (passing JVM arguments through command line or _wrapper.conf_) and not in the Anypoint Studio. Probably you have to continue your development with the _mule-app.properties_ entry for **code** and then configure your server (configuring the property using other method) when deploying the application on it.

Answer (score 4):

The *-M* is a way of passing arguments to the JVM if you are using the standalone Mule only. In studio you just need to pass `-D`.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error when I'm using the JVM. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Also don't put the `-D` on the program arguments but rather on the VM arguments.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks  Víctor. (passing only -D to the VM arguments)